# Hot to create custom sliver appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

Can anyone help me to build custom sliver app bar like sliver app bar on this picture. First condition is expanded state, second condition is collapsed state.
I don't know how can I create sliver that will be shaped as I want.[check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zppJO.jpg)

Comment: first check `SliverPersistentHeader` class

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the answer! Can you provide me an example, please.